# java set time based on input

Tags: java, timer

In my code I have a couple of objects:

- An `ArrayList` with an object. The object has a value (timeNeeded) which is the time as an `int`. the arraylist is in the model and can be checked to see if it contains an object with :  `model.isWaiting()` and the value of that object can be returned with `model.getdelay()`
- A `Timer` (Swing), that needs to run the values in the `ArrayList`, which is filled from another class.

Logic involved includes the following:

- If the `ArrayList` is empty it needs to check every 1 millisecond, if there is a new value.
- If there is a new value set the timer to the first value from the array, after the timer finishes the given time (from the first object in the `ArrayList`) it needs to delete the first object and set timer to 1 millisecond until there is another object added.

Here's my code:

```
Timer myTimer;
Model model;

public className(Model modelInput) implements ActionListener 
{
    model = modelInput;
    myTimer = new Timer(1, this);
    myTimer.start();
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
{
    //see if there is an object in the arraylist.
    if (model.isWaiting())
    {
        // if the delay is currently not equal to the delay given in the object waiting. set the delay to the time given by the object 
        if ( myTimer.getDelay() != model.getdelay())
        {
              myTimer.setDelay(model.getdelay());
        }
        // if the time waited is equal to the time given by the object waiting remove the object and set the timer to check again every 1 milisecond.
        else
        {
              System.out.println("runned after "+myTimer.getDelay());
              model.removeFirst();
              myTimer.setDelay(1);
        }
    }
}
```

So it should only delete from the model via `removeFirst()`, if there is an object waiting (`myTimer.setDelay(model.getdelay());`) and the delay is set to the delay required by the object.

But for some reason the timer goes off too early. If I print the delay, it is the right delay. But if I look at real time, it runs the else statement almost 6 times too fast: it is not the same as printed.

Is there a mistake in my code that makes the timer run at the wrong moment?

The delay from the `model.getdelay()` is always bigger then 1000 so it can never equal 1. Thus the code reaches the else statement. I also tried replacing `model.getdelay()` with raw value of 3000 and it didn't make a difference.

### Summary

Basically what I want is that, if there is a object in the `ArrayList` (i.e. `model.isWaiting() == true`) the timer is started with the value of that object (`model.getdelay()`). If the time given in that object has passed, then I need to remove the object from the `ArrayList` with `model.removeFirst()`. In other words:

1. Check if there is a object.
2. Run the timer with time given amount of milliseconds in the object.
3. Remove the object.

Comment: Sorry, but your question makes absolutely no sense to me

Comment: @peeskillet wich part. basicly what i want is if there is a object in the arraylist (of the model) start the timer with the value of that object. i the time given in that object is passed i need to remove the object from the arraylist. (with model.removeFirst())